# carousel - Set caroseul to a fixed height and prevent images from stretching outside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently having difficulties with the images on my carousel. The images in the carousel keeps bursting outside of the container. I have also tried many stack overflow solutions and none of them seems to answer my problem.

I would like to have my carousel image with a maximum height of 500px; and fit all images inside the container. Unfortunately, setting max-height on inner items cuts them off. I have tried adding `img-fluid` to it, still nothing seems to work.

Here is the code.

```
<div class="container" style="max-height:500px;">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="assets/img/shop.png">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="assets/img/m1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div


<style type="text/css">
    .carousel{
        background: #000000;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .carousel .item{
        min-height: 280px; /* Prevent carousel from being distorted if for some reason image doesn't load */
    }

    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }

    .carousel .item img {
        min-width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
```

The two images are of size,

2355 x 975,
1844 x 2048

Comment: Not sure if it is a typo but you are missing the open < for your styles above.  It would be helpful if you can create a code example complete with your question (Click the <> icon when editing your question).
Another tip would be to keep your images all the same size for a carousel.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand your question but i kinda get what the problem is.

There is many solutions to this.

- Solution - 1

  Make the container that holds the image to `height:500px` and use    photoshop 
  or any online tool to make the image's height 500px.
- Solution - 2

  Make the container that holds the image to `height:500px` and make    image 
  `height 100%` So it will fit in.
- Solution - 3

  Use object-fit property.

.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please give the owl-carousel javascript. Have you used owl-carousel class of your sliders div.